# ( item.area_partition.homepage_show || item.area_partition.name ) not meet my requirement

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a snippet code:

```
        <Col
          span="8"
          v-for="(item,index) in this.data"
        >
          <Card>
            <p slot="title" style="">{{ item.area_partition.homepage_show || item.area_partition.name }} </p> 
            <div>
              <Row :gutter="5">
                <Col span="12"  :key='index'>
                <Card :padding='5' class='business-type'>
                  <router-link to="/home/aftersale_physicalserver_workpanel/true/+ (item.area_partition.homepage_show || item.area_partition.name)"> # there do not get my requirement.
                    <span class="icon">
                      <Icon type="ios-barcode" :size='28' color='#ff9900'></Icon>
                    </span>
```

See the `{{ item.area_partition.homepage_show || item.area_partition.name }}`, if the `item.area_partition.homepage_show` is null, there will use `item.area_partition.name`.

it can works fine in there:

```
<p slot="title" style="">{{ item.area_partition.homepage_show || item.area_partition.name }} </p>
```

but the `router-link` is not my requirement:

```
<router-link to="/home/aftersale_physicalserver_workpanel/true/+ (item.area_partition.homepage_show || item.area_partition.name)">
```

I mean I can not use the bellow method to realize my requirement:

```
"/home/aftersale_physicalserver_workpanel/true/+ (item.area_partition.homepage_show || item.area_partition.name)"
```

my requirement is if the `item.area_partition.homepage_show` is not null, add it. if is null, should use  `/home/aftersale_physicalserver_workpanel/true/ + item.area_partition.name`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be happen for example when object(item) does not have property area_partition

Comment: How to realize my requirement?